# How to group by date not with time

Tags: mysql

My query return like below

```
date                    count
November 19,2019,11:58 PM 2
November 19,2019,11:59 PM 2
November 20,2019,12:02 AM 2
```

Is there any way to do like

```
November 19,2019 4
November 20,2019 2
```

Comment: Use the `DATE()` function to get the date of a `DATETIME`.

Comment: this is not standard mysql format, the answer is depending on how you group and how you show result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this query:

[image]

I get this result when I execute the query

```
select count(*) from listings  group by date(created)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems your date is not a standard **mysql** date time format. We need to format it first using `str_to_date` function.

```
select cast(str_to_date(dateC, '%M %d,%Y,%h:%i') as date), count(1) from Test
group by cast(str_to_date(dateC, '%M %d,%Y,%h:%i') as date)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=ysHtqlMFSf).